# Stopping parent page from overriding iframe style

Tags: css, iframe

I am very very new to this, so I apologize if this is very simple or has been asked elsewhere.

I am using Responsive Table Generator to generate a table from a Google document that I then try to place on a webpage using their iFrame code.

The generator gives me a handful of `.js` files and a `.html` and `.css` file to upload to my site. I then use the provided iFrame code to embed it on the page I want.

```
<div id="table-iframe-container"></div>
  <script src="http://nesemc.com/test/markdown-3/news-table/pym.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var pymParent = new pym.Parent(
      'table-iframe-container',
      'http://nesemc.com/test/markdown-3/news-table/index.html', {});
  }());
  </script>
```

However, I believe the parent page is some how overriding the `.cs`s style of the generated table.

You can see an example here: [LINK](http://nesemc.com/test/markdown-3/)

How can I stop this?

Comment: I see no styles being leaked into the iframe from the parent.

Comment: The table should be displayed like this: [link](http://nesemc.com/test/markdown-3/news-table/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your styles aren't leaking.  Your `iframe` isn't wide enough to see the "full view", and you have styles that are responsive and don't work when that small.  Make your `iframe` wider and it'll look like you want.  If you remove `max-width: 960px;` from the `#affero-page` styles in consolidated.css, you should see it.

To see what you are looking at, go to this page: http://nesemc.com/test/markdown-3/news-table/index.html?initialWidth=860&childId=table-iframe-container (your iframe content), and play with the browser width.  You will see once you get too small, it then displays how you have it.

Comment: Yep -- you are entirely correct! This really helps. Thank you so much!